# Python structure for storing list of items with frequency

Tags: python, data-structures

I spent the last 2 hours googling and can't find an answer. Hopefully, you'll be able to advise me.

I'm looking for a python structure where I could store a list of items with their occurrence. E.g.:

```
{["item1","property1"]:10, 
 ["item2","property2"]:5,
 ["item3","property3"]:5}
```

and then I'd be able to call something like `popitem()` which would return for example ["item3","property3"] and the structure would updated to following:

```
{["item1","property1"]:10, 
 ["item2","property2"]:5,
 ["item3","property3"]:4}
```

any idea? Thanks!

Comment: how does the `popitem()` know that it is supposed to pick out the last one?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you realize you cannot have `list` as keys in `dict`?

Comment: So what you want is a [counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for things?

Comment: So what you are saying is that you are looking for a subclass of `dict` that specialises in counting elements? https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: lifezbeautiful – this is not important for the question. It can be random or the last one. Honestly don't care. It returns a value and decreases frequency. The important here is the data structure that would allow such a way of storing data.

buran – very helpful, yes I'm aware of it. That's why I'm asking what data structure would allow me such a thing. I don't want to end up with an array where will be millions of the same items and then choosing from them. I want to just say that this item can be chosen exactly X times. (not probability but exactly)

Comment: Yes, collections.Counter is exactly what you want. Note however that it requires its keys to be "hashable" objects. So you can have `{("item1","property1"):10, 
 ("item2","property2"):5,
 ("item3","property3"):4}`, but you cannot have `{["item1","property1"]:10, 
 ["item2","property2"]:5,
 ["item3","property3"]:4}`

Answer (score 0):

You want a subclass of `dict` specialized in counting occurrences. That subclass already exists: [`collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Note that `Counter`, like all `dict`s, requires its keys to be hashable objects, so that:

- you can have `Counter({("item1","property1"):10,   ("item2","property2"):5,  ("item3","property3"):4})`;
- you cannot have `Counter({["item1","property1"]:10,   ["item2","property2"]:5,  ["item3","property3"]:4})`.

**Demo of Counter with random.choices**

```py
import collection
import random

l = [('item1', 'property1'), ('item1', 'property1'), ('item1', 'property1'), ('item1', 'property1'), ('item1', 'property1'), ('item1', 'property1'), ('item1', 'property1'), ('item1', 'property1'), ('item1', 'property1'), ('item1', 'property1'), ('item2', 'property2'), ('item2', 'property2'), ('item2', 'property2'), ('item2', 'property2'), ('item2', 'property2'), ('item3', 'property3'), ('item3', 'property3'), ('item3', 'property3'), ('item3', 'property3')]

c = collections.Counter(l)

print(c)
# Counter({('item1', 'property1'): 10, ('item2', 'property2'): 5, ('item3', 'property3'): 4})

for i in range(10):
  item, prop = random.choices(list(c.keys()), weights = list(c.values()), k = 1)[0]
  print(item, prop, end=', ')
  c[(item, prop)] -= 1

# item1 property1, item1 property1, item2 property2,
# item2 property2, item3 property3, item1 property1,
# item1 property1, item3 property3, item1 property1,
# item1 property1,

print(c)
# Counter({('item1', 'property1'): 4, ('item2', 'property2'): 3, ('item3', 'property3'): 2})
```

**Demo of Counter with random.sample**

```py
import collections
import random

c = collections.Counter({("item1","property1"):10,   ("item2","property2"):5,  ("item3","property3"):4})

popped = random.sample(list(c.keys()), 10, counts=list(c.values()))
c = c - collections.Counter(popped)

print(popped)
# [('item2', 'property2'), ('item2', 'property2'), ('item3', 'property3'),
#  ('item1', 'property1'), ('item1', 'property1'), ('item1', 'property1'),
#  ('item3', 'property3'), ('item1', 'property1'), ('item1', 'property1'),
#  ('item3', 'property3')]

print(c)
# Counter({('item1', 'property1'): 5, ('item2', 'property2'): 3, ('item3', 'property3'): 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a dict with mutable keys (such as lists) in python. You can use tuples instead.

To make `popitem()` acts like this, you must wrap your dictionary in an object and implement your own function.

```
class youClass(dict):
    def popitem(self):
        key=next(iter(self.keys())) #get one key, will act similary to pop()
        if self[key]>1:
            self[key]-=1
        else:
            del self[key]
        return key
```

You create your dict this way :

```
yourDict = yourClass({("item1","property1"):10, 
 ("item2","property2"):5,
 ("item3","property3"):5})
```